# Fire a function on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to add a color picker to some input elements.
I'm using:

```
$(".element").colorPicker(){ ... }
```

This works perfectly.
The problem is that the page has a AJAX form, which - when submitted - will overwrite the previous form with a new one (new input fields etc). After that the `colorPicker` stops working.

So how can I fire that function to the newly created inputs too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reattach the invocation in the ajax callback, since I don't believe there is a reliable event you can use to `.live` or `.delegate` it, without revealing more information.

Comment: so I add the `<script> $(".element) ... </script>` part again in the ajax response?

Comment: In the ajax `success` function, reinvoke `.colorPicker`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work:

```
$(".element").live('click focus', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('hasColorPicker')) {
        $this.colorPicker({ /* ... */ }).data('hasColorPicker', true);
        $this.click(); // trigger the color picker - assuming it binds itself to the click event
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What meder says is good, but also, if you are creating the new elements by copying existing ones, consider using `$.clone(true)` to make your copies and it will carry over existing event bindings too.